# Encode String of 20 characters to 8 characters, and Decode it back

Tags: encryption, cryptography, compression, decode, encode

I want to know a way to encode a Plain Text of 20 characters to a Cipher of 8 characters and Decode it back to 20 characters.

The possible constituent characters are :

> Like how in HexaDecimal number, the characters ranges from **'0 to F'**, for our PlainText it ranges from **'0 - A'** (base 11).
>
> The required Cipher can have combination of letters and numbers only. It should not have symbols in it.

I want a compression technique or even a program would be more helpful to both encode and decode the above requirements.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible.
11^20 (672749994932560009201) is too bigger than 36^8 (2821109907456).
(11 means count of '0-A', 36 means count of 'A-Z' & '0-9').
At least 238469969 (11^20/36^8) of the plan texts will be encoded as the same output.

Comment: You neglected that you could use both upper and lower case letters, i.e. you should be comparing 11\*\*20 with 62\*\*8.

Comment: I was going through the SHA-256 encryption algorithm. I learnt that no matter what the length of the plain text is, The length of the cipher, i.e. the Hash text is always 64 bytes. So only this idea of above encryption came to my mind.

Comment: 256^64 is big enough, and Hashing only means Encoding without Decoding. (Hash never provide a decoding algorithm, and you can not decode a hash value.)